# scala use template type to resolve sub class

Tags: scala

I am fairly new to Scala and trying to do some code reuse. I have two enums AB and AC, both extend A which is a trait with some common methods.

```
object AB extends A[AB]{ 
  val X = Value("x")
}

object AC extends A[AC]{ 
  val Y = Value("y")
}

trait A[T] extends Enumeration{
def getProperty(prop: T.Value): String = {
  //some code that uses prop.toString
}
```

I am trying to have a getProperty method that will restrict users to only Enums from the enumeration that it is being called upon.

if I call AB.getProperty() than i should be able to pass only X. if I call AC.getProperty than I should be able to pass only Y

If I have to redesign my classes that is fine. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what `ConfigProperties` is in your code, and why you need the type parameters, but the answer to your question is, declare the parameter type in `geProperty` as `Value` -> `getProperty(prop: Value)`.

`Value` is a nested abstract class in `Enumeration`, so it will be expanded by the compiler respectively to `AB.Value` and `XY.Value`, depending on the instance. A simplified example which you can test in the REPL:

```
object AB extends A {
    val A = Value('A')
    val B = Value('B')
}

object XY extends A {
    val X = Value('X')
    val Y = Value('Y')
}


trait A extends Enumeration {
    def getProperty(prop: Value): String = {
        //some code that uses prop.toString
        prop.toString()
    }
}


AB.getProperty(AB.A) // OK
XY.getProperty(XY.Y) // Also OK

// AB.getProperty(XY.X) <- this won't compile
//                         Error:(21, 20) type mismatch;
//                         found   : A$A238.this.XY.Value
//                         required: A$A238.this.AB.Value
//                         AB.getProperty(XY.X)
//
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, ConfigProperties is actually A, forgot to replace that. But works. I was trying to use Type.Value as parameter type instead of just using Value